# How to dismiss firebase notification on tap in react native

Tags: react-native

How to dismiss notification on tap in reactnative.

I have integrated notification in react native and its working, but when notification tap i want to dismiss notification.

I'm receiving call back into below function.

```
firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen)  => {
         const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;

         console.log("Notification Received - " + body)    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```html
notification.android.setAutoCancel(true);
```

to your code

```html
this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification(notification => {
            console.log("OnNotification", notification)
            notification.setTitle("MyApp")
            notification.android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
            notification.android.setAutoCancel(true) //add this line
            notification.android.setChannelId("test-channel")
            firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
    })
```